# Show only certain amount of variables in an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a small array list in a PHP var: **$string**

```
Array
(
    [0] => tablet-android.png
    [1] => to_pa3923u1lc3_100.png
    [2] => index_articleImage-Monitor.png
    [3] => floppy.png
    [4] => call.png
    [5] => usb.png
    [6] => mphone.png
    [7] => window.png
    [8] => speaker.png
    [9] => WinZip.png
)
```

And if a run this code:

```
foreach ($string as &$img) {
   echo $img."<br>";
}
```

It will display the complete list,

But I want to set the amount of items to display, example, set to display only the first 5... is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo $string[$i]."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this without using loops like a `for` or a `while` by simply making use of the **`PHP`** functions.

### - Using `array_slice` (preferred)

```
print_r(array_slice($arr,0, 5));
```

### - Using `array_chunk`

```
print_r(array_chunk($arr, 5)[0]);
```

---

### The code..

```
<?php
$arr=array
(
    0 => 'tablet-android.png',
    1 => 'to_pa3923u1lc3_100.png',
    2 => 'index_articleImage-Monitor.png',
    3 => 'floppy.png',
    4 => 'call.png',
    5 => 'usb.png',
    6 => 'mphone.png',
    7 => 'window.png',
    8 => 'speaker.png',
    9 => 'WinZip.png'
);
print_r(array_slice($arr,0, 5));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/100298)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [ArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/ArrayIterator), if you like:

```
$iterator = new ArrayIterator($arr);

//get the first two array elements starting from 0
$limitArr = new LimitIterator($iterator, 0, 2);

foreach ($limitArr as $value) {
  echo $value . '<br />';
}
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/100287)